# Publishing Tiles from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, tiles, arcgis-pro

I am trying to create tiles in the "Manage Tiles" section of "Settings" for this layer: http://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/nAQVsl698blIdU3d/arcgis/rest/services/United_Kingdom/MapServer

When I created the package in ArcGIS Pro I set the level of detail to 12 and then uploaded it to my account.

I seem to only be able to get this far in publishing:

[image]

This seems strange that my storage for each scale is limited to 0.14 or 0.15 MB.  I cannot see any way that I have limited by storage at the organizational level.

Comment: Do you have administrative privileges?

Comment: I am the administrator.

Comment: --Poke this sleeping question. Is this still an issue? I'd guess after letting it work for minutes/hours the tiles were generated. Did they get generated?